# Is there a possible way to change the source variable during runtime using iText7?

Tags: java, text, itext7

For instance, in the following lines setting a fixed source and destination is done for virtually every example I've found so far.

```
...

public class FetchBookmarkTitles {
    public static final String DEST = "./target/txt/bookmarks.txt";

    public static final String SRC = "./src/main/resources/pdfs/bookmarks.pdf";

    ...
```

Changing the type to something other than *public static final String*  will not work as an argument for will cause an error in the following line which brings me to the issue. In the long run, I would like the user to select the path rather than have a fixed path relative path.

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC));
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do and you don't post your error, but have you taken a look in the API docs at the many different constructors of `PdfReader`? You can use a filename (`String`) as in your example code, but you can also use a `java.io.File` or a `java.io.InputStream`. See https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.12/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfReader.html

Comment: @Javier this is more of a general programming question rather than a question about iText. Parameter passed to `PdfReader` can be any `String`, not necessarily a `static final String`. So just get the right `String` (file path) from the user first and then pass it to `PdfReader`

Comment: @AlexeySubach... That's exactly what I did. I passed in a string with a proper file and I get a java.lang.NullPointerException error. It seems like only accepts the type described in my question. Thank you.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I'm sorry it's my first time around because I usually find that the solution is already answered somewhere. I'll give your proposal a go.

Comment: Post your code, in such a way that it is reproducible for other people.

Comment: Thank you both for the valuable insight. You were both right. The issue was related to the specific pdf document I was using to run the test and not the type of the source.